# Swift how to change the background color of status bar lise navigation bar for a view, not all view

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I added a navigation bar in a view, but the **background color** of status bar is not the same with my navigation bar. like this:
[image]

I searched informations on internet, I can find how to change the color of status bar, but I can not find how to change the **background color** like the color of navigation bar... Could you help to resolve this problem : to set the **background color** of status bar like color of navigation bar for a view ? Thank you.

Comment: You change the barTint color to change the color of the navigation bar. Also, make sure the bar is not translucent. This issue looks more like a translucent thing than the wrong color, but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to change the **background color of status bar**, not a navigation bar... I can change the color of navigation bar...but I can not change the **background color of status bar**

Comment: oh the status bar only has like 2 colors, you physically have to put a view behind the status bar in your controller and change the color of that. You can change the status bar color by overriding preferredStatusBarStyle and returning UIStatusBarSyle.(style enum value here). You might be able to set a bar tint... or possibly set a generic tint for your app somewhere but i don't remember. There is no direct way to change the background color of the status bar.

Comment: I think there is no direct way to change the background color of the status bar too... I added a label behind the status bar, but the background color of the part battery is not changed...So, could you give me a clear answer with the code? Thank you very much !

Comment: did you add a background color to the label ?

Comment: Yes, but  the background color of the part battery is not changed..

Comment: oh you want to change the battery power color ? that, i think, is impossible

Comment: I added a label, after the background color of status is the same with the color of label without background color of the part battery, background color of the part battery is always not changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

Comment: Hello, this is **color of status bar**, it is not **background color of status bar**

Comment: then you can try this: 
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {

    guard  let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")?.valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView else {
        return
    }

    statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of status bar if you are using the gradient layer.Here is the code just try it and do let me know.

```
let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 69/255, green: 90/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 44/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, 375, 64)

  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Comment: Please mark a tick over the answer .Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't ask OP to pick your answer.